# Is it possible to view the year followed by the month in Bootstrap Calendar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

Currently, the bootstrap datepicker shows me a view where I see "March 2013".

Is there a way to change the settings while initialising the calendar to view "2013 March"?

I haven't seen anything of this nature in the docs.(https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: What “bootstrap calendar” are you referring to? AFAIK bootstrap does not include a calendar component, so I’m assuming you are referring to some kind of plugin or such.

Comment: I am referring to this https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ @CBroe

Comment: Well if that doesn’t offer a specific option for this, then you will either have to change the part of the script that generates that calendar view, or maybe change the content of the according DOM element by hitching on to one of the events the plugin provides.

Comment: do you know of any cleaner way to do this? I want to use the DOM way .. but does not seem to be the best way to do so. @CBroe

Comment: Maybe ask the author if they would consider making this configurable in a future version. Until then, I think modifying the source code yourself might be the most viable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading all of the documents. This is currently not possible out of the box. However as @Cbroe above has commented - DOM can be manipulated to do the same.

There is no direct way to do this currently.